# How do I assert the exception thrown in the constructor?

Tags: c#, xunit

In my service class, I have this constructor.

```
public IngestService()
{
    _extractedFilePath = configuration["Path:Ingest"];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_extractedFilePath))
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Invalid conguration. Check appsettings.");
        throw new Exception("Invalid conguration. Check appsettings.");
    }
}
```

and I have this test using XUnit

```
[Fact]
public async Task WhenInvalidConstructor_ThenShouldThrowETest() {
        var _ingestService = new IngestService();
}
```

When I debug it, it can reach the constructor. But how do I capture the exception and assert the exception message "Invalid conguration. Check appsettings."?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017295/assert-an-exception-using-xunit

Comment: BTW, [a good read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77639/when-is-it-right-for-a-constructor-to-throw-an-exception)

Comment: @ShaiAharoni, I tried but unable to get it since it is not calling any method but the constructor. If call any method, I can get the exception message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assert an Exception using XUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017295/assert-an-exception-using-xunit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
    Exception actualException = Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => new IngestService());
    Assert.Equal("Invalid conguration. Check appsettings.", actualException.Message);
```